Softbody Vehicle Physics Like Beamng
I want to implement softbody vehicle damage like Beamng for my Burnout inspired game. The softbody physics dosen't need to be 100% accurate.
The problem is that I don't understand how to implementing this. I am using Godot Game Engine.

Do you require full soft body simulation? Older racing games with vehicle damage (including some entries in the Burnout franchise if I recall correctly) would handle this by chopping the car into chunks, and modelling a few different levels of smashed-in-ness for each chunk. Then in a crash, they swap an impacted chunk for its more-damaged version. That let them get excellent detail and artistic control with low simulation cost. And players usually wouldn't notice the crunched parts looking similar from one crash to another — their focus was on the driving and the crashing itself.

@DMGregory yes that can be used for my game but how would I implement full softbody physics like Beamng?
